# Conditionally process an XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am facing difficulty in converting an xml file using xslt. My criteria is if the input xml has a particular node in it, then apply xsl logic to all elements. if that node is not present, do not apply logic. the xsl I have is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="Root/Order">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Order1/task or Order2/task or task">
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="Order1">
            <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="Order2">
            <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input files structure is as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root>
    <Order>
        <cust>
            <Date>2018-04-16</Date>
            <name>abc</name>
            <code>xyz10</code>
            <custId>abc123</custId>
            <System>main</System>
            <Number>TANK</Number>
        </cust>
        <make>
            <Indi>A</Indi>
          <Number>BA22299</Number>
          <Status>O</Status>
          <Code>SEK</Code>
          <Class>3B</Class>
        </make>
        <Order1> <!-- It can also be Order2 -->
            <task>  
                <tasks>
                    <lno>010</lno>
                    <val>100</val>
                </tasks>
            </task>
        </Order1>
        <task>  
            <tasks>
                <lno>010</lno>
                <val>100</val>
            </tasks>
        </task>

    </Order>
</Root>
```

In the above example, I want to check if 'task' node is available in input and then apply template.

I tried different cases but every time, xsl is processing the input file irrespective of 'task' node.

1. I tried `<xsl: if test = task>` inside for each loop, `<xsl: if test = Order1/task>`, inside for each loop.
2. I tried another choose when condition after first one.

   ```
   <xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:when test = "Order1/task or Order2/task or task">
         <!-- for each from above xsl >
       </xsl:when>
   <xsl:choose>
   ```

but I couldn't obtain the required result. Please advise where I am doing mistake and a better way to write the conditional logic on a node in input file.

The output for the above input looks as below.

```
|abc123|main|TANK|BA22299|O|A|SEK||
||||||||010|100
||||||||010|100
```

Comment: So which result do you want if the `task` element is present and which result do you want if the `task` element is not present?

Comment: If the task node is present, I need to apply template to the input xml -  ie the when condition for header and the for-each to generate tasks at root level. if It is not present, do not apply when condition and for-each loops. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you please update the input XML and show some data for `<cust>` and `<make>` elements and the required output if `<task>` node is available / not available. There are way too many loops related to `<task>` and it is difficult to guess what the output look like.

Comment: Hi Aniket, thanks for response. I updated input file. the output is a pipe delimited file. If there is no task node in input xml, I need a blank output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verbal description to apply the template only if the task node is present translates into

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Order[Order1/task or Order2/task or task]"/>
<xsl:template>
```

then you can remove the checks from your template, i.e. change it to

```
<xsl:template match="Root/Order">
            <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="task">
            <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="Order1">
        <xsl:for-each select="task">
            <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="Order2">
        <xsl:for-each select="task">
            <xsl:value-of select="ID"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/custId"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/System"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="cust/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Number"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Status"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Indi"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="make/Code"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/lno"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tasks/val"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```